# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DeleteContent'

Tags: exchange-2013

I am attempting to run this command:

```
Get-Mailbox | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery '(Received:01/01/2010..31/12/2013)' -DeleteContent
```

but I receive error message:

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DeleteContent'.
```

I have searched this error message online and viewed other solutions like ensuring the account has **Mailbox Import Export Role**. I checked and this role is part of **Organization Management**, which Administrator is a member of.

Answer (score 0):

Your user must be assigned the roles: Discovery Management and Mailbox Import Export role.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638205(v=exchg.150).aspx